# Do I need Parallels Pro to run Visual Studio?

Tags: development, parallels-desktop

I'm considering installing Parallels to use Visual Studio for my personal use. Can I use the standard $80 version of Parallels? Or do I really need to commit to $100 a year for the Pro version?

Comment: did you use the pro version or the standard one?

Comment: I didn't follow through with either unfortunately. I've been using VS for Mac and VS Code instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the pro version offers support for larger memory and more cpu cores. The said VS plugin offers cross-platform debugging and testing, as well as many other automation and command-line support for it.

This doesn't, however restrict that you're able to install VS on the virtual machine.

Therefore it would be possible for your use case.